# how to get the values or indexed from nested array and compare conditions

Tags: java

how can i display the value john or mary or alice or bob separately? 
from the sample nested array.

```
String[][] kstemmers = new String[][] {
    {"John", "Mary"}, 
    {"Alice", "Bob"}
};
```

Comment: Take a look at [Oracle's tutorial on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: `kstemmers[0][0]` -> `"John"`, `kstemmers[0][1]` -> `"Mary"`, `kstemmers[1][0]` -> `"Alice"`, `kstemmers[1][1]` -> `"Bob"`

Answer (score 1):

Think of the 2d array as a table (columns and rows).

So essentially you have:

```
John Mary
Alice Bob
```

Now turn that into a table using those columns and rows, you get something like this:

```
     0       1
  ________________
0 | John  | Mary |
1 | Alice | Bob  |
```

So to get "Mary", you would use `kstemmers[0][1]`

There are Java 8 stream solutions available, but figured it would be better for you to understand the basic concepts of 2d arrays before providing that.

Comment: thanks, i having error on this System.out.print(Arrays.toString(kstemmers[0][0]));

Comment: Because you don't need `Arrays.toString` - when you use `kstemmers[0][0]` it returns a String

Answer (score 1):

Use Stream with Java 8:

```
    Arrays.stream(kstemmers)
            .map(kstemmer -> String.join(" ", kstemmer))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use java8 "flatMap" to play around. One way could be following

```
List<String> collection = Arrays.stream(kstemmers).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then iterate over List